# What novel had a time travel car and dinosaurs?

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel, dinosaurs

I am trying to remember the title of a science fiction novel about a man who has a car that can travel back in time, and he can park it about 10 seconds ahead, so no one but him can see it.  He travels to the time of the dinosaurs and likes it there, so he goes to the middle ages to find a pretty woman who has no relatives and takes her with him to live among the dinosaurs.

I read this book about 20 years ago, and the library no longer has it.

Anyone know this novel?

Comment: That's one I'd like to read. Hope someone knows it. :)

Comment: I found this list of novels about dinosaurs; none seems to fit well your description but it might be worth reading it to see if anything rings some bells: http://prehistoricpulp.blogspot.com.es/search/label/novels. About cars and dinosaurs, the only I can find is `Cadillacs & Dinosaurs` (aka Xenozoic Tales), but still does not fit well your description and it is a comic series.

Comment: Maybe it's Back to the Future part IV and hasn't been written yet....

Comment: *Dinosaur Planet* has some matching bits, as does *A Very Strange Trip*. But nothing I can find about parking 10 seconds ahead.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds similar to but different from ["*The Number of the Beast*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Number_of_the_Beast_%28novel%29) by Robert Heinlein.  The car has an AI and was called the Gay Deceiver.  The car had the ability to travel through time and dimensions.  I thought they encountered some dinosaurs but it has been decades since I read the book.

Comment: There were 4 people travelling in the Gay Dieciever, and all of them were from Modern times (ie time of the origional start of the time travelling) None were from the past. So it is unlikely to be the OPs. Also while the car might have been able to do time travel (cant remember for sure) I think it was mainly able to travel to alternate universes. (some fictional)

Comment: Gay Deceiver was more of a time and alternative reality travelling spaceship than a car.